# How to implement custom validation in Blazor

Tags: validation, blazor

How I can implement validation to my model, but not use attributes in `this` class, because, `this` class has some behavior of dependency on how to fill properties.
For example, if property `IsDropDown` is true, I must validate only `DropDownValue` else I must validate other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)
Read Steve Sanderson's Blog : [Integrating FluentValidation with Blazor](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/04/blazor-fluentvalidation/)
And Chris Sainty's article : [Using FluentValidation for Forms Validation in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/)

Comment: Thanks! I will be checking this solution, but the look is good right now.